# How to read a csv column value like: "[1,2,3,nan]" with pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to read in a csv file that has a list for each column value.
Example:

```
accuracy_per_item
"[0.2,0.3,0.4]"
"[0.4,0.2,nan]"
```

While I can read in the column values without nan using:

```
pd.read_csv('accuracy_per_item.csv', converters={'accuracy_per_item': pd.eval}
```

However when pd.eval encounters "nan", it returns an error.

--> UndefinedVariableError: name 'nan' is not defined

How can I read in this csv with pandas recognizing "nan" as np.nan?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a customized converter

```py
def handle_nan(x):
    x = x.replace('nan', '"nan"')
    lst = pd.eval(x)
    lst = [np.nan if i == 'nan' else i for i in lst]
    return lst

df = pd.read_csv('accuracy_per_item.csv', converters={'accuracy_per_item': handle_nan})
```

```
print(df)

  accuracy_per_item
0   [0.2, 0.3, 0.4]
1   [0.4, 0.2, nan]
```

Comment: This fixes everything, thanks a lot!